# Cryptic crossword #36

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

Fairly straightforward, I think.

[image: Grid]

Across
1 Changing climate? Ban car transport (8,5)
8 As Aladdin rubs his lamp, the contents turn to fire (4)
9 CBBC hit is a calculated insult to woman of conventional tastes (5,5)
10 "Hello, sadness" with internal expression of resignation (2,4)
11 Moving, for old woman confined to bed, is a wrench (8)
12 Separatist beer-drinking rifle association lady ignoring odds (9)
14 Ultimate goal: a success at finals (4)
15 Not strong on amusement parks - throws up (4)
16 Pillowcases and sheets for men Spooner is executing (9)
20 Chase, and sow chaos into demonstration (8)
21 Prison riots make one mad (6)
23 Break-in is from raging infernos (10)
24 Suggestion from bride and groom (4)
25 Perhaps Egyptian I'd led astray with high teas will stop me joining navy (6,7)

Down
1 Makeup would be more vibrant without foundation from Boots (7)
2 Rigged ocean vessel (5)
3 Buller is ravaged by a disease (7)
4 Get-together with a measure of deviation surpassed by bachelors (9,6)
5 Regarding Chanel's first rust-proof coat (6)
6 German woman and German man described first type of crime (4,5)
7 Leave work, head off strike by management (7)
13 Point to Archers cast who are regularly barred (9)
15 Dawkins' profession upset his mate (7)
17 Reveals Canadian team recruiting wingers from Singapore (7)
18 Enthusiastic to the end, granny gets fabric (7)
19 Lady Gaga caught going in with fingers (6)
22 Is the centre of Raetihi coming up? You could ask here (1-4)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A good puzzle with a variety of devices. I found it tough and perhaps not as straightforward as the author claims. It took me two sessions to solve the puzzle.

> There are several occasions where words have to be separated and where hyphenated words are treated as if the hyphen weren't there. There's also more repositioning, i.e. changing the order of wordplay parts, than usual. That's by no means unfair, though, and once you start looking for these devices, the puzzle yields steadily.

(Below, definitions are in hold. Not all positional indicators are explained, but should be clear.)

#### Completed Grid

> ```
>            B A C T R I A N C A M E L
>            L   A   U   S   O   A   O
>          B U R N   B A S I C B I T C H
>            S   O   E   O   O   L   K
>          O H W E L L   C R O W F O O T
>            E       L   I   N   R   U
>          B R E A K A W A Y   L A S T
>                R       T       U
>            A I R S   B E H E A D I N G
>            T   O   D   D   X       A
>          S H O W C A S E   P R I O N S
>            E   H   C   G   O   S   K
>          F I R E S T O R M S   I D E A
>            S   A   Y   E   E   T   E
>            M I D D L E E A S T E R N
> ```

#### Across

> **1** Changing climate? Ban car **transport** (8,5)
>           **BACTRIAN CAMEL** — anagram ("changing") of CLIMATE BAN CAR
>
>  **8** As Aladdin rubs his lamp, the contents turn **to fire** (4)
>          **BURN** — hidden ("contents") backwards (turn) in "Aladdi[N RUB]s"
>
>  **9** CBBC hit is a calculated insult to **woman of conventional tastes** (5,5)
>          **BASIC BITCH** — anagram ("calculated") of CBBC HIT IS A
>
>  **10** "Hello, sadness" with internal **expression of resignation** (2,4)
>          **OH WELL** — W ("with") in ("internal") anagram ("sadness") of HELLO.
>
>  **11** Moving, for old woman confined to bed, is a **wrench** (8)
>          **CROWFOOT** — anagram ("moving") of FOR O(ld) W(oman) inside COT ("bed")
>
>  **12** **Separatist** beer-drinking rifle association lady ignoring odds (9)
>          **BREAKAWAY** — AK (Kalashnikov, "rifle") + A ("association") in BREW ("beer")
>          + (l)A(d)Y ("ignoring odds")
>
>  **14** **Ultimate** goal: a success at finals (4)
>          **LAST** — last letters ("finals") of (goa)L A (succes)S (a)T
>
>  **15** Not strong on amusement parks - **throws up** (4)
>          **AIRS** — (f)AIRS ("amusement parks") without F (*forte*, "strong" in music)
>
>  **16** Pillowcases and sheets for men Spooner is **executing** (9)
>          **BEHEADING** — Spoonerism of HE BEDDING ("pillowcases and sheets for men")
>
>  **20** Chase, and sow chaos into **demonstration** (8)
>          **SHOWCASE** — anagram ("chaos") of CHASE SOW
>
>  **21** Prison riots **make one mad** (6)
>          **PRIONS** ([neurally harmful proteins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prion)) — anagram ("riot") of PRISON
>
>  **23** Break-in is from raging **infernos** (10)
>          **FIRESTORMS** — REST ("break") inside anagram ("raging") of IS FROM
>
>  **24** **Suggestion** from bride and groom (4)
>          **IDEA** — hidden ("from") in "br[IDE A]nd"
>
>  **25** **Perhaps Egyptian** I'd led astray with high teas will stop me joining navy (6,7)
>          **MIDDLE EASTERN** — anagram ("astray") of ID LED
>          + anagram ("high") of TEAS, both inside ("stop") ME + RN (Royal Navy)

#### Down

> **1** **Makeup** would be more vibrant without foundation from Boots (7)
>          **BLUSHER** — B(oots) + LUSHER ("more vibrant")
>
>  **2** Rigged ocean **vessel** (5)
>          **CANOE** — anagram ("rigged") of OCEAN
>
>  **3** Buller is ravaged by a **disease** (7)
>          **RUBELLA** — anagram ("is ravaged"9 of BULLER + A
>
>  **4** Get-together with a measure of deviation **surpassed by bachelors** (9,6)
>          **ASSOCIATE DEGREE** — ASSOCIATE ("get together")
>          + DEGREE ("measure of deviation", i.e. for angles)
>
>  **5** Regarding Chanel's first **rust-proof coat** (6)
>          **COCOON** — COCO ("Chanel is first") + ON ("regarding")
>
>  **6** German woman and German man described first **type of crime** (4,5)
>          **MAIL FRAUD** — homophone ("described") of MALE ("man")
>          + FRAU (German for woman) + D (*deutsch*, "German")
>
>  **7** Leave work, head off **strike by management** (7)
>          **LOCKOUT** — (c)LOCK OUT ("leave work" without its head)
>
>  **13** **Point to Archers** cast who are regularly barred (9)
>          **ARROWHEAD** — anagram ("cast") of WHO ARE (b)A(r)R(e)D ("regularly")
>
>  **15** **Dawkins' profession** upset his mate (7)
>          **ATHEISM** (as described in "The God Delusion" by [Richard Dawkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Dawkins))
>          — anagram ("upset") of HIS MATE
>
>  **17** **Reveals** Canadian team recruiting wingers from Singapore (7)
>          **EXPOSES** — S(ingapor)E ("Wingers", i.e. outer letters)
>          inside ("recruiting") [former Montreal baseball team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montreal_Expos) EXPOS
>
>  **18** Enthusiastic to the end, granny gets **fabric** (7)
>          **NANKEEN** — NAN ("granny") + KEEN ("enthusiastic")
>
>  **19** Lady Gaga caught going in with **fingers** (6)
>          **DACTYL** ("finger" in Greek) — CT ("caught") inside anagram ("gaga") of LADY
>
>  **22** Is the centre of Raetihi coming up? **You could ask here** (1-4)
>          **I-SITE** (a [visitor information centre in NZ](https://www.tourismnewzealand.com/tools-for-your-business/i-site-new-zealand/))
>          — IS + reverse ("coming up") of ra(ETI)hi ("centre of")

Comment: Which one's the backward indicator in 8A? And why is W=With? And what's the use of "first" in 6D?

Comment: @Sid: w=with is pretty standard, at least in the crosswords I solve. 6d is using first the same way 5d is (which I hadn't noticed until now) which is to change the order of the elements of the wordplay.

Comment: I have edited the explanation of 8a slightly to answer @Sid's question.

Comment: I was still living in the USA in 2004. How did I miss that bit of sports news?

Comment: Excellent. Some of these are really clever.

Comment: Cool. Do you even Google? :)